# Spring controller main methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I'm new to Spring and Spring MVC. I'm trying to implement a basic web-application to test the functionalities of this framework and I'm finding some difficulties.

I discovered that from version 3, annotations brought many advantages so, controller classes do not have to implement abstract classes (i.e. `SimpleFormController`), but this means that there are not mandatory methods to implement.

So my question is: which are the common useful methods that one should implement in a controller class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to implement the methods you wish to correspond to the actions from your various webpages - e.g. to accept the input of a form.

What specific difficulties are you having?

Comment: That's right, but for example, building a form (and after several headaches) I discovered that to bind a custom objects collection to a select I have to implement `PropertyEditorSupport`. It could be helpful to know in advance which classes or methods to use to obtain a fully functional controller class...

Comment: I understand, but your vision of a fully-functional class is probably different to others - Spring isn't going for the one-size-fits-all approach of a framework like Struts (to pick an example at random). I appreciate that this makes it difficult to pick up at the start, but lends itself to cleaner and lighter code later. I'd suggest having a look at some of the Spring sample apps they provide, they're quite illuminating. For other questions, people here are happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

The methods will have relevant annotations to denote that they should be invoked for a particular URL. For example in following code (taken from [Official Doc.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)),

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
    public String helloWorld(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!");
        return "helloWorld";
    }
}
```

`helloWorld(Model model)` is just any method in a any class. What makes it special is the annotation `@RequestMapping` which tell that this method should invoked when the requesting URL is `/helloWorld`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Santosh I recommend you look at the official doc and the Javadoc: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html

Basically instead of overriding methods your going to use annotations on methods and based on the parameter annotations and method arguments different things will happen. The Javadoc above states the equivalent annotations to be used instead overriding the simpleform methods.

Here is a complete example of CRUD controller that I generated with Roo:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/timers")
public class MyTimer {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
    public String create(@Valid Timer timer, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            populateEditForm(uiModel, timer);
            return "timers/create";
        }
        uiModel.asMap().clear();
        timer.persist();
        return "redirect:/timers/" + encodeUrlPathSegment(timer.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "form", produces = "text/html")
    public String createForm(Model uiModel) {
        populateEditForm(uiModel, new Timer());
        return "timers/create";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = "text/html")
    public String show(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model uiModel) {
        uiModel.addAttribute("timer", Timer.findTimer(id));
        uiModel.addAttribute("itemId", id);
        return "timers/show";
    }

    @RequestMapping(produces = "text/html")
    public String list(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size, Model uiModel) {
        if (page != null || size != null) {
            int sizeNo = size == null ? 10 : size.intValue();
            final int firstResult = page == null ? 0 : (page.intValue() - 1) * sizeNo;
            uiModel.addAttribute("timers", Timer.findTimerEntries(firstResult, sizeNo));
            float nrOfPages = (float) Timer.countTimers() / sizeNo;
            uiModel.addAttribute("maxPages", (int) ((nrOfPages > (int) nrOfPages || nrOfPages == 0.0) ? nrOfPages + 1 : nrOfPages));
        } else {
            uiModel.addAttribute("timers", Timer.findAllTimers());
        }
        return "timers/list";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "text/html")
    public String update(@Valid Timer timer, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            populateEditForm(uiModel, timer);
            return "timers/update";
        }
        uiModel.asMap().clear();
        timer.merge();
        return "redirect:/timers/" + encodeUrlPathSegment(timer.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", params = "form", produces = "text/html")
    public String updateForm(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model uiModel) {
        populateEditForm(uiModel, Timer.findTimer(id));
        return "timers/update";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = "text/html")
    public String delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size, Model uiModel) {
        Timer timer = Timer.findTimer(id);
        timer.remove();
        uiModel.asMap().clear();
        uiModel.addAttribute("page", (page == null) ? "1" : page.toString());
        uiModel.addAttribute("size", (size == null) ? "10" : size.toString());
        return "redirect:/timers";
    }

    void populateEditForm(Model uiModel, Timer timer) {
        uiModel.addAttribute("timer", timer);
    }
}
```